# Criteria based sharing filter does not include formula fields?

Tags: sharing-rule

I have a formula field that is a value from a look up object. Now when into sharing by criteria, I am unable to view this formula field in order to filter by criteria.

Now is it safe to assume that this is a formula field and hence will no be available in the pick list and is there a way I can filter using this formula field? If the assumption is true?

Comment: Seems you have edited your question with a follow up question. That will classify as a different question. The way SFSE works is that we try to limit it to one question/specific issue. I will recommend you to open a new question with the details you are looking to achieve. As a pointer, you can achieve that using a workflow field update/process builder/trigger. There are quite a few ways you can do that.

Comment: i am still learning to edit and post in this forum. thanks will do as you have suggested

Comment: That's absolutely fine. We are all here to learn. The only reason to keep the problem specific is so that the original question does not get lost with multiple other follow ups.

Comment: Additionally, if you think this question was resolved, then you should mark the answer as accepted. This helps for anyone coming to this question to identify if this answer was accepted or not. You will need to select the *tick* mark near to the answer to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your finding is correct. You **cannot** have formula field in available field list in Criteria based sharing rule. There is [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hDvDAAU) open to allow formula fields in criteria based sharing.

Your only option is to utilize the fields which are available in the fields list. In your case you can copy over the values on a text field and then utilize accordingly.

Comment: how do i mark as accepted

Comment: @SmithaVikram take a look at this [help article](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for details on the process.

Answer (score 0):

I created an app to solve this problem. Its called Unleash Your Formula https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000MS8T1EAL.

It simply copies and syncs formula fields to non-formula fields. This allows you to use the synced "static" (non-formula) field in your sharing rules. Voila.